# KnockoutJS update row sum field

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm stuck on how to update row sums in a foreach template using knockoutJS

```
    <div id="timeEntryList" data-bind="foreach: timeEntries">
        <table >
            <tr>
                ...

                <td>  //there are more of this, not included here
 <input type="number" 
    data-bind="value: Days[6].Hours, 
               event: { change: $root.setDirty }" />

                </td>
                <td> //this part needs to be updated when the above input is changed
                    <span data-bind="text: $root.sumRow($data)">
                    </span>
                </td>
```

The last TD there contains a span element which displays the sum of hours reported for the current item in the foreach.
it displays correctly when the data is loaded, but then stays stale when I edit the elements. 
How can I make this element update as I change the values of the input boxes?

Here is my view model in a very slimmed down version:

```
var TimeReportModel = function (init) {
    this.timeEntries = ko.observableArray(init.TimeEntries);

    //... helper functions
};
```

TimeEntries are objects representing a reported hours per week.
So it contains an array of days and each day has an hour property.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you're binding to, it appears you're binding to the result of a regular function.  If you want to see the values updated when there are changes, you need to bind to an observable.  Make the sum a computed observable in your view model and bind to it.

I have no idea what your view model looks like or what you are adding up but it would look something like this:

```
// calculate the sum of the hours for each of the days
self.totalDays = ko.computed(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.days(), function (day) {
        sum += Number(day.hours());
    });
    return sum;
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/mDkc2/) to demonstrate.

Comment: How would this work when all of it is inside an foreach template? there will be a sum for each row, that is, I can't have a single observable for this , there needs to be one for every rendered row

Comment: We'll you'll have to show me what your view model looks like and your data, I can't give you a straight answer until I know what I am dealing with.

Comment: I'm sorry but what you've added is still not enough for me to understand what the big picture is. Did you look at the fiddle I created? You'll need another view model for each `TimeEntry` object you have and place this computed observable in that.